# Objective-C Core Data: Access data from child of child

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, core-data

I'm slowly figuring out Core Data for my iPad app, but I just can't seem to figure out how to access data from my to-many children (who also have to-many children).  I'm hoping to get some code examples from the experts here.

Let's use a simple data structure: Parent -(to many)-> Child -(to many)-> Toy

I can fetch the Parent just fine and get it's data and the NSSet of children. After that, I get lost.

1) What would the code look like to get the data from a Child (say, get a specific Child's age or ALL the children's ages in the NSSet?

2) How would I then get the NSSet of the Toys a specific Child has? (also assuming accessing the Toy data would be the same as #1 code).

I sincerely appreciate the help!  This is supposed to be EASIER... isn't it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

1) All the childrens' ages: `NSSet *ages = [parent.children valueForKey: @"age"]`;

To get a particular child you need to specify that child. You could just use `[parent.children anyObject]` but it's likely you care which answer you get, in which case you can filter the set. Check out the `NSSet` documentation, specifically the `filteredSetUsingPredicate` method.

2) Having got your specific child, you just ask for its `toys` property.

Easier than what?

Comment: Easier than... SQLlite or a flat database?  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Would [parent.child anyObject] return an NSManaged object or a Child object?

Comment: @Matt: depends on your managed object model. By default it'll be an NSManagedObject.

Answer (score 1):

If this line :

```
NSSet *children = [parent children];
```

gets you an `NSSet` of child objects then

```
NSManagedObject *child = [[parent children] anyObject];
```

should get you a (random) Child object. From this object you should just be able to do

```
NSNumber *age = [child age];
NSSet *toys = [child toys];
```

or have I missed something in the question?